# Why does the test-RMarkdown in R-Studio give an html that does not show any results after pressing the knit-button?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I opened a new R Markdown file in R studio and got the default small working example.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Katharina Zweig"
date: "30. Januar 2016"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax   
for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using 
R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that 
includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks 
within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to 
prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

It says, you only need to press the `knit` button to create an HTML 
containg the text, the code and the results of the code. I got some long 
error logs that were hardly helpful. Neither did changing the output to 
PDF and Word - same result: text was there, code was there, no results of 
running the code. By producing the output, the original file vanished.

What is wrong?

Comment: Well, without seeing those _long error logs_ that were probably _actually really helpful_, I'm not sure how anyone will help you.

Answer (score 1):

When the `knit` button is used on a file not yet saved, it asks you under which name to save it. The file needs to be saved as an Rmd file - just give no extension and R-Studio will do it right. Then, the file does not vanish and the resulting document contains the results of the r commands. I thought it asked where to save the **output** and gave it the extension of the output file, i.e., either myfile.html / myfile.pdf / myfile.doc.

Answer (score 0):

In the chunk option try this:

`{r, results='asis'}
summary(cars)`

You can also embed plots, for example:

`{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
plot(cars)`

The results = 'asis' command should output the tables and graphs if not please let me know.